# 'Python manage.py runserver' "ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins'".:

Tags: python-3.x, django, virtualenv

I'm working on a Django project.

When starting the server I get "ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins'".
I'm in the correct directory, with virtual environment started.

I can't make migrations, same error apears.

Everything was working fine was able to start the server on this method in the past with no problem, until today.

Thanks in advance!

Version:

Windows 10
Python 3.8.1
Django==3.1.5

```
frego@Yisus-Robles MINGW64 ~/Desktop/news
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\frego\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 563, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "c:\users\frego\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 744, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.reporter_class = import_string(reporter_class or settings.DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER)
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "c:\users\frego\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\views\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.views.generic.base import View
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 914, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1342, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1314, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1443, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1483, in _fill_cache
OSError: [WinError 1392] El archivo o directorio est▒ da▒ado o es ilegible: 'C:\\Users\\frego\\.virtualenvs\\frego-6ij68a4f\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\views\\generic'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py", line 71, in configure_logging
    logging.config.dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)
  File "c:\users\frego\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 808, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "c:\users\frego\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 570, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 370, in execute
    _parser = self.fetch_command('runserver').create_parser('django', 'runserver')
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 244, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 37, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "c:\users\frego\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import (
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import LimitedStream
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers import base
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .exception import convert_exception_to_response
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.views import debug
  File "C:\Users\frego\.virtualenvs\frego-6ij68a4f\lib\site-packages\django\views\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.views.generic.base import View
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 914, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1342, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1314, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1443, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1483, in _fill_cache
OSError: [WinError 1392] El archivo o directorio est▒ da▒ado o es ilegible: 'C:\\Users\\frego\\.virtualenvs\\frego-6ij68a4f\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\views\\generic'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error is arisen from the LOGGING in the settings of the project. Take a look in the LOGGING['handlers'].